# SMTP gmail Client works strange with different host

Tags: c#, email, gmail, smtpclient

I have the following code written in C# for sending messages:

```
bool ret = false;
MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("addressfrom@gmail.com", "Name");
string fromPassword = "MyPassw";

        try
        {
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                //Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                //Port = 587,
                //EnableSsl = true,

                Host = "rs.t-home.mk",
                Port = 25,
                EnableSsl = false,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
            };

            System.Web.UI.WebControls.MailDefinition md = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.MailDefinition();
            md.From = "addressfrom@gmail.com";
            md.IsBodyHtml = false;
            md.Subject = subject;
            System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary replacements = new System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary();
            MailMessage msg = md.CreateMailMessage("mailTo@address.com", replacements, body, new System.Web.UI.Control());//belinaljupce@belina.com.mk
            smtp.Send(msg);
            ret = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            ret = false;
        }
```

While testing this code locally, with this SmtpClient settings:

```
Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
Port = 587,
EnableSsl = true
```

Everything is fine, I can send message, also into the Send folder of my Gmail account I can see all send messages from this SmtpClient

But when I publish this code on server, where I must use this SmtpClient settings:

```
Host = "rs.t-home.mk",
Port = 25,
EnableSsl = false
```

I can send e-mail, normally, it works fine, but into the Send folder of my Gmail account I don't see the send message from this SmtpClient, although the mail is send (I've checked, and "mailTo@address.com" receive the message)
So I'm curious what causes this, and wonder how to fix this.

Comment: What has the second case got to do with Gmail?, your sending via `rs.t-home.mk` - how would email sent via that server end up in your Gmail sentbox?

Comment: basically, i'm front end developer and I was told from the company where my page was hosted that I must use this Settings.. And i still have no clue how this works, cause I have gmail that is sending my messages via rs.t-home.mk, but it's working, whenever i send mail from "from@gmail.com", and when i checked the "sendTo@gmail.com", the mail is received from "from@gmail.com", but when I open "from@gmail.com" the folder send is empty

Answer (score 0):

> I can send e-mail, normally, it works fine, but into the Send folder of my Gmail account I don't see the send message from this SmtpClient, although the mail is send (I've checked, and "mailTo@address.com" receive the message) So I'm curious what causes this, and wonder how to fix this.

This occurs because `rs.t-home.mk` is not a Gmail SMTP server. The easier "fix" is to include your Gmail account on BCC.